# Code First: FOREIGN KEY constraint may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm working on an application related to the education industry, and I have the following set of classes.

```
public class Person : EntityBase<long>
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Middle { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
}

public class Student: Person
{
    public string AdmissionId { get; set; }
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    public List<GuardianLink> Guardians { get; set; }
    public StudentStatus Status { get; set; }       
}

public class Guardian: Person
{
    public GuardianType GuardianType { get; set; }
    public List<GuardianLink> Students { get; set; }     
}

public class GuardianLink: EntityBase<long>
{
    [Required]
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guardian Guardian { get; set; }

    public Boolean IsEmergencyContact { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsAllowedToPickup { get; set; }
}
```

When I tried to create the database from these classes, I received an error that this would result in circular cascading deletes.  So I added the following.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<GuardianLink>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.Guardian)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<GuardianLink>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.Student)
            .WithMany()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

I expected this to resolve the issue, but I'm still getting an error.

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_dbo.GuardianLinks_dbo.People_Student_Id' on table 'GuardianLinks'
>   may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO
>   ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY
>   constraints.

I want to configure this so that deleting a student deletes the associated links, but not the guardian, and vice versa when deleting a guardian. Why didn't this resolve the issue?  What should I be doing instead?

Comment: The referenced student has a GuardianLink property which will point to other students, which is a cycle in EF's book. You should map the inverse navigation properties so EF knows these won't cascade either.

Comment: I don't follow you. The Student does have a GuardianLink property, but that should only point back to itself.  Unless maybe I haven't configured it so EF understands that?  I'll do some research on "map inverse navigation property" and see if that helps.

Comment: .HasRequired(c => c.Guardian)
            .WithMany() means: GuardianLink has a Guardian with many GuardianLinks, which are not mapped in the property. You'll have to tell EF the Students property in Guardian is the same Guardian as the one we came from using .HasRequired(c=>c.Guardian).WithMany(c=>c.Students)

Comment: Got it! Thanks, worked perfectly (after I remembered to delete my initial migration and create a new one).